# Solving an Equation Involving Modular Exponation

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

Is it possible to solve the following equation? 
$$ 3^k\mod k \equiv 24 $$

Clearly $k>24$; does a solution definitely exist, and can it be found in any simple way? I can certainly calculate $$3^{25}\mod 25\equiv 18$$ etc.

Comment: The equation is equivalent to $$ 3^k=ak+24 $$ an here you can conclude for instance that $k$ is not a prime, and you can discuss the first cases $k$ and $3$ are not coprime, $k$ even and see what happens... All this to say that the question is incomplete and you certainly need to add your attempts at least the obvious ones !

Comment: is your equation equivalent?'it is solved by a=1, k=3; but k=3 is not a solution of the first equation?? Thanks for your help

Comment: you assumed in the biginning that $k>24$, and that's not a problem in just take in a account that $a$ could be negative

Comment: So we see k cannot be even. Why can we conclude k is not prime?